# Redirect to home page when some one type detail url address

Tags: c#, asp.net

Redirect to home page when some one type detail url address

like typed url address www.abc.com/admin.aspx

Redirected to open url address www.abc.com/home.aspx

Comment: Do you want to redirect to home page even if that page exists? Are you trying to prevent people from linking to your sub-pages?

Comment: Have a look on https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/preventing-open-redirection-attacks-in-c-sharp-and-javascript/